Keep columns and rows that contains "FAIL" in pandas dataframe
I would like to keep columns that contains word "FAIL".
Input data:



Values1
Values2
Values3
Status1
Status2
Status3




1
1
1
PASS
PASS
FAIL


2
2
2
PASS
PASS
PASS


3
3
3
PASS
PASS
PASS


4
4
4
PASS
FAIL
PASS



Expected output:



Status2
Status3




PASS
FAIL


FAIL
PASS



Current Output:



Status1
Status2
Status3




PASS
PASS
FAIL


PASS
FAIL
PASS



My code:
import pandas as pd
values = range(1,5)
status_pass = ["PASS"]*len(values)
status1 = status_pass[1:]+["FAIL"]
status2 = status1[::-1]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values1":values,"Values2":values,"Values3":values,"Status1":status_pass,"Status2":status1,"Status3":status2})
# drop unwanted rows
words_to_keep = ["FAIL"]
df = df[df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: all(x.str.contains(w, case=False).any() for w in words_to_keep))]
# Filter by column name
df = df.filter(like='Status', axis=1)


Some problem with my answer?

Use boolean indexing with any:
df.loc[:, df.eq('FAIL').any()]

# or for multiple words
# the mask doesn't matter as long
# as you have True/False
df.loc[:, df.isin(words_to_keep).any()]

Output:
  Status2 Status3
0    PASS    FAIL
1    PASS    PASS
2    PASS    PASS
3    FAIL    PASS

How it works:
df.eq('FAIL').any()

Values1    False
Values2    False
Values3    False
Status1    False
Status2     True
Status3     True
dtype: bool

# which is equivalent to
df.loc[:, [False, False, False, False, True, True]]


Use DataFrame.loc for filter rows and columns by mask, if need filter by list use DataFrame.isin, if need filter scalar use DataFrame.eq with DataFrame.any for test for at least one match:
words_to_keep = ["FAIL"]
m = df.isin(words_to_keep)

#m = df.eq("FAIL")

out = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), m.any()]
print (out)
  Status2 Status3
0    PASS    FAIL
3    FAIL    PASS

Details:
print (df.isin(words_to_keep))
   Values1  Values2  Values3  Status1  Status2  Status3
0    False    False    False    False    False     True
1    False    False    False    False    False    False
2    False    False    False    False    False    False
3    False    False    False    False     True    False

print (m.any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True

print (m.any())
Values1    False
Values2    False
Values3    False
Status1    False
Status2     True
Status3     True
dtype: bool

